# border-radius: 50%; does NOT make a circle

Tags: html, css

The blue circle surrounding number "1" in `ol.circle > li::before` class is not a circle at all. Why? [Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/vLf2hgc0/1/) the JSFiddle.
Don't pay attention to colored `borders` - they are *only* to control visually that all objects are vertically centered.

```css
.meaning {
  color: #1f2c60;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: calc(0.5em + 2.3vw);
  border: 1px solid red;
}

ol.circle {
  position: relative;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 2.7em;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

li {
  line-height: calc(0.5em + 2.3vw);
  counter-increment: item;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

ol.circle > li::before {
  transform: translateX(-150%);
  content: counter(item);
  display: inline-flex;
  border-radius: 50%;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #1f2c60;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid purple;
 }
```

```html
<div class="meaning">
<ol class="circle">
<li>THIS is my text</li>
</ol>
</div>
```

Comment: It would improve this question if you included why you think that your code should product a circle, and what you did to try and troubleshoot the issue yourself

Answer (score 1):

Well, To make it a circle. You have to put the same value of `height` and `width`

**e.g.**

```css
.meaning {
  color: #1f2c60;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: calc(0.5em + 2.3vw);
  border: 1px solid red;
}

ol.circle {
  position: relative;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 2.7em;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

li {
  line-height: calc(0.5em + 2.3vw);
  counter-increment: item;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

ol.circle > li::before {
  transform: translateX(-150%);
  content: counter(item);
  display: inline-flex;
  border-radius: 50%;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #1f2c60;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid purple;
  height:30px;
  width:30px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="meaning">
<ol class="circle">
<li>THIS is my text</li>
</ol>
</div>
```

**UPDATED ANSWER**

How about this? I have added `padding: 4px 0 4px 2.7em;` to your `ol.circle` eleent.

```css
.meaning {
  color: #1f2c60;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: calc(0.5em + 2.3vw);
  border: 1px solid red;
}

ol.circle {
  position: relative;
  list-style-type: none;
  /* padding-left: 2.7em; */
  padding: 4px 0 4px 2.7em;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

li {
  line-height: calc(0.5em + 2.3vw);
  counter-increment: item;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

ol.circle > li::before {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateX(-150%);
  content: counter(item);
  display: inline-flex;
  border-radius: 50%;
  justify-content: center;
  background: olive; /* #1f2c60 */
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid purple;
  width: calc(0.5em + 2.3vw - 2px);     /* CIRCLE BOTTOM TOUCHES GREEN BORDER WITHOUT "-2px" */
  height: calc(0.5em + 2.3vw - 2px);    /* CIRCLE BOTTOM TOUCHES GREEN BORDER WITHOUT "-2px" */ 
 }
```

```html
<div class="meaning">
  <ol class="circle">
      <li>THIS is my text</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Jesper, I tried height and width before posting this question, but it didn't work: as you see i use `calc` to dynamically change font size depending on viewport size, so when i plug `calc(0.5em + 2.3vw)` as **height** and **width** of the circle, it becomes ideally round, but its bottom touches the green border. Here is the fiddle which works 100% i want it to work (https://jsfiddle.net/gycko1vn/), but i have to **deduct** `2px` from both `height` and `width` - in **this** case circle is ideally round and vertically centered between green borders. Any ideas why this happens, please? Thank you!

Comment: @HexenSage Did you check my updated answer at the bottom?

Comment: Your updated variant _includes_ the solution **i've** added (with `-2px` part), so it just increases padding. If i **delete** `-2px` part and leave yours (`padding: 4px 0 4px 2.7em`) the circle moves closer to the bottom green border, i.e. becomes **not** centered vertically. So finally, my solution seems to be the only working so far, but i'm still curious **why** should i deduct those `2px` instead of using your `padding` approach, which is not working - while it's the first one to come to one's mind (which is absolutely logical).